# How to use javascript and HTML template to fill the div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display element (book) which has newBook attributes in     `<div id = "newBook"></div> .` It is webpack project. Please tell me if I need some additional imports or something like that.

```
export class Book {
        constructor(price, title, image, description) {
            var bookTemplate = '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">\
            <div class="card">\
            <a href="#"><img class="mx-auto-d-block-card-img-top-fixed-top" src="{image}" width="335" height="340"\
            alt=""></a>\
            <div class="card-body">\
            <h4>{title}</h4>\
            <h5>{price}</h5>\
            <h5>\
            <a href="#">Kup teraz!</a>\
            </h5>\
            <p class="card-text">{description}</p>\
            </div>\
            <div class="card-footer">\
            <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</small>\
            </div>\
            </div>\
            </div>';
            var result = bookTemplate.replace("{title}", this.title);
            result = result.replace("{image}", this.image);
            result = result.replace("{price}", this.price);
            result = result.replace("{description}", this.description);
            return result;
        }
    }

    export function initBook() {
        var newBook = new Book();
        newBook.title = "Chów i hodowla trzody chlewnej";
        newBook.image = "swinie.jpg";
        newBook.price = "135zł";
        newBook.description = "Podręcznik, który wyjaśnia jak chodować świnie.";
        newBook.transform();
        $("#newBook").html(newBook.transform());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're really close to a solution. I cleaned up your code a little bit to make it a little clearer in what you're doing. First in your book class, there was no need to do all of the string replacement and doing a return based off the replacements. What you really could do, and what you see here is to use a simple template literal and do the replacements directly from your constructor parameters being passed in. Notice the ${} syntax, that's the replacement values. So now you have a simple book class with a single property of bookTemplate.

Book class example:

```
export class Book { 
   constructor(price, title, image, description) {
       this.bookTemplate = `
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
               <div class="card">
                  <a href="#">
                     <img class="mx-auto-d-block-card-img-top-fixed-top"
                          src="${image}" width="335" height="340" alt="${image}"
                          style="border: solid 1px #999999;"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>${title}</h4>
        <h5>${price}</h5>
        <h5>\
          <a href="#">Kup teraz!</a>
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">${description}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</small>\
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `;
  }
}
```

Now in the initBook function I created a simple object literal with the properties that needed to be passed in on your new Book constructor. Then we grab the id of an element on your HTML page so that we can replace that with our book template. We create a new book with the params from earlier and last we assign the new book template to the HTML target on the page by again doing a template literal and calling the bookTemplate property from the Book class. Finally, we just call the function initBook() to render the template to the page.

initBook Function example:

```
export function initBook() {
var params = {
    title: "Chów i hodowla trzody chlewnej",
    image: "swinie.jpg",
    price: "135zł",
    description: "Podręcznik, który wyjaśnia jak chodować świnie."
};

   const book = document.getElementById("newBook");
   const elements = new Book(params.price, 
                          params.title, params.image,params.description);
    console.log(elements);
    book.innerHTML = `${elements.bookTemplate}`;
}

initBook();
```

HTML example of the target div to be replaced:

```
<div id="newBook"></div>
```

For your convenience here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-templating-sample-okowsp?file=index.js) of the code provided above.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I can't just call initBook(). It's webpack project and this last line seems to be invisible and id doesn't affect html. Simply - nothing happens. I think I should make a script tag in my Book.html and there call this function but I'm not sure how to do this. Another question: to which "this" in the third line refers? and how this element of code is called: "    `${elements.bookTemplate}`   "?

Comment: Please explain it

Comment: @mikolaj -  Because you're inside of a constructor of the class, you need to refer to the property, so by calling "this.bookTemplate" you're referring to the correct property.

Comment: And I can't call initBook() this way

Comment: @mikolaj - How do you envision calling that function? Right now I have no idea about the rest of the application so the example I provided was enough to execute the function and have the rest of the code follow through. But simply, you will have to call "initBook()" in some fashion to kick off this block of code.

Comment: I have index.js file where I have some imports amd I think it would be something like: " import { initBook } from './js/Book.js';

export { initBook }; And then in my Book.html i'm trying to use initBook() in script tag

Comment: @mikolaj - You will have to adjust the example code some then to include the iniBook function as part of the Book class. What you're saying is very close to  your solution. I believe with a little work you will have a fully functional Book class to work with.

Comment: I also don't understand idea of using: ` and $ and {} in the end. Please explain what these characters do. I will be greateful.

Comment: I really don't know how to adjust this code. Please help me.

Comment: @mikolaj - Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals